# Knockout.js dynamic links do not click through

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, knockout.js

I am working on a new project that is using knockout js.  I have setup a small table that displays images and info entered into a form that populates an observable array.  I have the images wrapped with an anchor (link) tag and I am feeding the in the href through the KO data-bind.  See below.

`<a data-bind="attr: {href: imgUrl}" target="_blank"><img class="imgThumb" data-bind="attr: {src: imgUrl}"/></a>`

All of this displays as expected, however none of the links will actually click through to the image location.

An array entry looks like this:

`col1: 'Bert', col2: 'Muppet', col3: 'Sesame Street', imgUrl: 'http://images3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20101210195428/muppet/images/4/40/Bert1970s.jpg'`

The rendered HTML looks like this:

`<a data-bind="attr: {href: imgUrl}}" target="_blank" href="http://images3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20101210195428/muppet/images/4/40/Bert1970s.jpg"><img class="imgThumb" data-bind="attr: {src: imgUrl}" src="http://images3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20101210195428/muppet/images/4/40/Bert1970s.jpg"></a>`

Once again, none of my links work, they will not click through to the image location as I expect them to.  Can anyone help me here and point out what I am missing.  Also, of note, I have tried adding a `click: function(){ return true; }` as well, and that didn't help either.  Thanks in advance and a demo can be found here: http://dev.voidbase.com/working.html

Comment: Very strange.  That should work.  @PWKad, browsers handle hrefs on anchors automatically.  No JavaScript should be needed once the href is set (which is its).  I can't see anything that's preventing the click.  JSpell, could you reproduce this in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are on the right track with

> Also, of note, I have tried adding a `click: function(){ return true; }` as well, and that didn't help either.

But in itself the `click: function(){ return true; }` is not enough because the `click` event will still bubble up so you need to use the `clickBubble: false` option (see in also in the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html#note_4_preventing_the_event_from_bubbling)):

```
<a target="_blank" data-bind="attr: {href: imgUrl}, 
      click: function() { return true;}, clickBubble: false">
    <img class="imgThumb" data-bind="attr: {src: imgUrl}"/>
</a>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PdjNr/).

By the way your click binding on the body element "steals" your click event: `<body style="padding-top: 100px;" data-bind="click: modalKiller">`. So if return `true` from your `modalKiller` handler it also fixes your problem.

Comment: This seems like a lot of work for a link. But it worked for me - thanks!

Comment: I logged ER https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/2565 to see if this can be improved because I also think having to do this is rather convoluted